# How to combine 2 CSV files in python using pandas with different column names?

Tags: python, csv, merge, data-science

I am in my second year of Data-Science at University so I am not that good at python yet, I currently have an Internship at an IT company and I have two CSV files; they contain the same people but are listed in differently named columns.

(Victoria Gonzales is in the ADA.csv file but also in the HRS.csv file, however the columns don't have the same name or there are different things in front of the first name column f.e the salary.)

I want to merge the files without duplicates, how can I do that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with pandas and indicate the different column names with `left_on` and `right_on`, position of the columns doesn't matter.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Might need some more information to give you the best answer. Could you reply with your current code and dataframes.

Have you tried--

```
df.drop_duplicates()
```

Are you are trying to map all the information to a specific person thats spread across both files?

Comment: I did not code any data frames yet because its the first time I am actually using pandas. I think I figured something out - I need the code to merge based on CSV1's First Name + Last Name Columns and CSV2's Name Column, since in the first csv they are listed separately but in the second one the name is listed in full in a single column.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).